# Curvature Map of an unwrapped .OBJ with WebGL

Tags: c++, python, 3d, webgl

is it possible to extract the curvature map of an unwrapped .OBJ file with WebGL? basically finding the edge like this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV9W5.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Mario

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to do an edge detection.
Edge detection is done using depth and  optionally, a normals map.
Here's one implementation: http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2010/06/edge-detection.html

Also, for curves, it's the same thing as for edges with that change that if you see a smaller depth change you account that for coloring as well because it actually is on a "curve".

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mario Pex, do you need something more that I could help with?